# Why does the compiler not recognize Node as a type? It is a private class within AVLTree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

```
class AVLTree{
    struct Node {
    K key;
    V value;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    int height;

    /**
     * Node constructor; sets children to point to `NULL`.
     * @param newKey The object to use as a key
     * @param newValue The templated data element that the constructed
     *  node will hold.
     */
    Node(const K& newKey, const V& newValue)
        : key(newKey), value(newValue), left(NULL), right(NULL), height(0)
    {
    }
};
```

==============================================================

```
Node* AVLTree::findParent(Node *&current, Node *& child ) {
if (current == NULL) {
    return NULL;
}
if (current->right == child || current->left == child) {
    return current;
} else {
    findParent(current->right, child);
    findParent(current->left, child);
}
```

}

Trying to write a function that finds the parent of a node in an AVL Tree so I can use it in the rotation functions. However whenever I try and compile I get this error:

```
tests/../avltree.cpp:72:1: fatal error: unknown type name 'Node'
Node* AVLTree::findParent(Node *&current, Node *& child ) {
```

Why is this happening?
Find parent is in avltree.cpp and is listed as a private member in the AVLTree class, so what's the issue?

I also tried doing AVLTree::Node, but then got this error:

```
AVLTree::Node* AVLTree::findParent(Node *&current, Node *& child ) {
^
tests/../avltree.h:20:7: note: 'AVLTree' declared here
class AVLTree
```

Comment: You have a missing `};` to end your struct Node definition.

Comment: looks like you are missing a '};' after the Node structure definition?

Comment: Yeah I didn't include the whole class cause it is massive, I guess I forgot a } sorry

Comment: You really should post code so that we can compile it and see the error.  You don't need to include anything massive to duplicate a compiler error.  For example, is this `AVLTree` a template class?  If so, why did you leave out the important `template <typename whatever>`?

Comment: Yes it is template<class K, class V>

Comment: @Robotic_Cow [Same compiler error, full example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f8600c936201727).  That is a [mcve] that we're looking for.

Comment: I forgot the templates, I got it working thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic issue is that the return type is parsed in the global scope, and not in the scope of the method (due to the fact that it is *before* the method name and its scope specifier).  So you need to explicitly scope it:

```
AVLTree::Node* AVLTree::findParent(Node *&current, Node *& child ) {
```

Comment: I did that I initially. The problem is that I got a different error, the AVLTree is define already one